# Concatenate vector integer with timestamp as the string in C++?

Tags: c++, string, boost, vector

I am trying to concatenate current timestamp in milliseconds with an integer that I have in my vector by using the below code -

Basically, I need to have `timestamp.integer` as the string

```
struct timeval tp;
gettimeofday(&tp, NULL);
uint64_t ms = tp.tv_sec * 1000 + tp.tv_usec / 1000;


struct timeval tp;
gettimeofday(&tp, NULL);
uint64_t ms = tp.tv_sec * 1000 + tp.tv_usec / 1000;

std::vector<uint32_t> myvector;
for (uint32_t i=1; i<=5; i++) myvector.push_back(i);

std::cout << "myvector contains:";

for (std::vector<uint32_t>::iterator it = myvector.begin() ; it != myvector.end(); ++it) {
       string id = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(ms)+"."+*it; // this line gives me exception?
       std::cout << ' ' << id;
       std::cout << '\n';
}
```

I want the result to be a String like this when it get printed out -

```
1384391287812.1
1384391287812.2
1384391287812.3
1384391287812.4
1384391287812.5
```

The exception that I get is -

```
error: no match for âoperator+â in âstd::operator+(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const _CharT*) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>](((const char*)".")) + it.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator*<int*, std::vector<int> >()â
```

Comment: You need to convert the `int` from the `vector` to a `string`.  Since you're already using `lexical_cast` you may as well use it a second time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want to convert the `uint32_t` referenced by the `it` iterator into a string

```
   string id = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(ms)+"."+ boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(*it);
```

you can't simply append an integer to the string since there is no `operator+(std::string&, uint32_t)` as the compiler correctly tells you.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you print the values, I wouldn't bother concatenating them into a `std::string`: that's just wasting CPU cycles and quite a number of them! Instead, I'd just dump the data into the output:

```
for (std::vector<uint32_t>::iterator it = myvector.begin() ; it != myvector.end(); ++it) {
   std::cout << ms << '.' << *it << '\n';
}
```

If you really want to get hold of the string, you would need to convert `*it` to a `std::string` before concatenating it with the other `std::string`. Note, that using `std::lexical_cast<std::string>(x)` is probably not too expensive but you should still minimize its use (especially when you try to format more interesting types for which it isn't specialized):

```
std::string base(boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(ms) + ".");
for (std::vector<uint32_t>::iterator it = myvector.begin() ; it != myvector.end(); ++it) {
   string id = base + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(*it);
   // ...
}
```